# Echo the nth line from a text file where 'n' is a command line argument

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple text file with numbers like:

```
12345
45678
34567
89101
```

I need a batch that will return the `n`th line from this file. `n` should be taken from a command line argument.

I am very new to batch scripting so Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: is this windows or unix?

Answer (score 6):

To get the file **from** the nth line you could use more +n (For line1 is n=0).
To split the rest of the file you could use a `FOR /F` loop.

This works even, if there are empty lines before the nth line.
It could be necessary to set the EOL to an unused character or to linefeed (default is `;`)

```
set "lineNr=%1"
set /a lineNr-=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`more +%lineNr% text.txt`) DO (
  echo %%a
  goto :leave
)
:leave
```

Comment: @jep, how can `eol` be set to line-feed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use batch file extension.

**token.bat**

```
 @echo off

 setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 set l=%1
 set c=0
 for /f "delims=" %%1 in ('type foo.txt') do (
   set /a c+=1 && if "!c!" equ "%l%" echo %%1%
 )
```

If you have a file like following,

**foo.txt**

```
 AAAA
 BBBB
 CCCC
 DDDD
```

And specify line number like following

```
 token 3
```

You'll get

> CCCC

Comment: +1, You are faster than me, but why you set the delims to `\` and `n`?

Comment: oops, I removed "\n". Thanks for notice.

Comment: Btw, your version removes all `!` and sometimes the `^` from the output line

Comment: Hmm, I can't understand "why this happen".

Comment: The `!` are removed as the delayed expansion is enabled, only with disabled expansion you can safely access `%%1` see also [Script to remove special characters from filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429604/script-to-remove-special-characters-from-filenames/4448017#4448017)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FOR /F` with the `skip` parameter:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET skip=%1
SET /A skip-=1
IF %skip% LSS 0 GOTO out
IF %skip% GTR 0 SET params="skip=%skip%"
FOR /F %params% %%L IN (filename) DO (SET "line=%%L"& GOTO out)
:out
ECHO %line%
```

The `skip` parameter means the `FOR /F` loop must skip the specified number of lines at the beginning. The parameter is only applied if you specify a line number greater than 1. If you specify a number less than one or a non-number, the script outputs an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Jeb's solution... I did not realize you could use the ***more*** command to skip lines like that!

Here is an alternate method that I use for getting a specific line from a file (or from the multi-line output of another program):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "C:\SomeFile.txt"') do (
  if "%%a" equ "%1" echo.%%b
)
```

I use **findstr /n .* "Path\FileName.ext"** to add line numbers, and to ensure no empty lines are skipped by the for loop.

I then set **"tokens=1* delims=:"** to separate the line numbers from the line content.

Finally, I compare the current line number (**%%a**) with the line specified by the **%1** parameter, and echo the line contents (**%%b**) on a match.

Answer (score 0):

## To Find Nth to Mth Character In Line No. L --- Example For Finding Label

---

```
@echo off

REM Next line = Set command value to a file  OR  Just Choose Your File By Skipping The Line
vol E: > %temp%\justtmp.txt
REM  Vol E:  = Find Volume Lable Of Drive E

REM  Next Line to choose line line no. +0 = line no. 1 
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`more +0 %temp%\justtmp.txt`) DO (set findstringline=%%a& goto :nextstep)

:nextstep

REM  Next line to read nth to mth Character  here 22th Character to 40th Character
set result=%findstringline:~22,40%

echo %result%
pause
exit /b
```

Save as find label.cmd

The Result Will Be Your Drive E Label

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Based off of Amit's Answer, I made a utility called **snip.cmd**.

USAGE: **snip FILE LINE FIRSTCHARACTER LASTCHARACTER**

example:

**foo.txt**

```
    //
    // File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
    //
    77752e4c91ba96dcc6c2bb4bdcdbdec5 c:\users\lapinot\desktop\token.bat
```

**snip foo.txt 3 0 33** will yield *77752e4c91ba96dcc6c2bb4bdcdbdec5*

**Here is my code for snipe.cmd (you can add snipe to your command line by copying snip.cmd to c:\Windows\System32)**:

```
    @echo off
    :: USAGE
    :: snip <file> [Line - Starts at 0] [First Column - Start Count at 0] [Last Colum]


    set file=%1
    set line=%2
    set char1=%3
    set char2=%4

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`more +%line% %file%`) DO (set findstringline=%%a& goto :nextstep)

    :nextstep
    echo echo %%findstringline:^~%char1%,%char2%%% > %temp%\result.bat
    %temp%\result.bat
    del %temp%\result.bat
    :EOF
    exit /b
```

Answer (score -3):

`echo "enter the line number.."; read i; awk 'NR==$i' <file_name>;`

Comment: The question is tagged as [batch-file], so your solution doesn't fit