# Batch Script - CALL another batch script to call line to perform certain command

Tags: batch-file, call

Is it possible to create a batch file with a bunch of commands *(commands.bat)*

```
ECHO HELLO
ECHO HOLA
ECHO KONICHIWA
ECHO ANYONGHASEYO
ECHO BONJOUR
```

, then within a different batch file, `CALL commands.bat` and only perform the command on line 2 or line 4 without knowing what is on those lines?

Comment: Yes, make `echo Hola` and `echo Bonjour` conditional, dependant on a certain argument and while calling `commands.bat`, send in that argument.

Comment: http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-branching.htm

Comment: Edited my question. Left out an important detail: calling them by line number and not by what their string contains

Comment: @sehe I'm not sure what you were trying to point me towards even with the original question.

Comment: @Mechaflash You can do one thing. Have a master `commands.bat` which will only contain the list of `echo` statements. Depending on the line number (or range) you may receive, copy the contents from that line number till the end of file into a separate file, `temp.bat` and execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I meant in my comment.

**master.bat**

```
echo abcd
echo hello
echo notepad
echo public
echo wind
echo balance
```

**command.bat**

```
@echo off

more +3 master.bat > temp.bat & temp.bat
```

Prints the below for me.

```
public
wind
balance
```

To start off from the first line, use `+0`.

If you want this number to be sent via command line, here is a slightly modified version:

**command.bat**

```
@echo off

more +%1 master.bat > temp.bat & temp.bat
```

You can run the above with commands such as `command.bat 0` or `command.bat 3`.

Comment: If you want to just execute the nth line and not n-through-EOF, you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409869/echo-the-nth-line-from-a-text-file-where-n-is-a-command-line-argument and combine it with my answer to get what you want.

Comment: I'm gonna use Jeb's answer from your linked post. Setting answer.

Answer (score 1):

A neat little trick I used to know (back when batchfiles were in vogue)

```
SET JUMPTO=HOLA
goto BRANCH_%JUMPTO% 

:BRANCH_HELLO
echo HELLO
GOTO :QUIT

:BRANCH_HOLA
echo HOLA
GOTO :QUIT

:BRANCH_KONICHIWA
echo KONICHIWA
GOTO :QUIT

:BRANCH_ANYONGHASEYO
echo ANYONGHASEYO
GOTO :QUIT

:BRANCH_BONJOUR
echo BONJOUR
GOTO :QUIT

:BRANCH_
echo Illegal branch?!

:QUIT
```

It becomes more intesting when you replace the first line with e.g. `SET JUMPTO=%1`

Some test output:

> **E:>.\test.cmd HELLO**
>
> ```
> E:\>SET JUMPTO=HELLO
>
> E:\>goto BRANCH_HELLO
>
> E:\>echo HELLO
> HELLO
>
> E:\>GOTO :QUIT
> ```
>
> **E:>.\test.cmd**
>
> ```
> E:\>SET JUMPTO=
>
> E:\>goto BRANCH_
>
> E:\>echo Illegal branch?!
> Illegal branch?!
> E:\>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Give me your input on this as a solution. It works, but I know some people don't like piping the FIND command to anything =/

```
REM Contents of COMMANDS.BAT
ECHO HELLO & ::1
ECHO HOLA & ::2
ECHO KONICHIWA & ::3
ECHO ANYONGHASEYO & ::4
ECHO BONJOUR & ::5

REM Command to perform ECHO KONICHIWA out of COMMANDS.BAT
CALL C:\COMMANDS.BAT | FIND "3"
```

Comment: It's a great idea! I will add another answer which is similar to what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, I discovered this playing around with it yesterday:

```
REM Contents of COMMANDS.BAT
ECHO HELLO & ::1
ECHO HOLA & ::2
ECHO KONICHIWA & ::3
ECHO ANYONGHASEYO & ::4
ECHO BONJOUR & ::5
```

-

```
REM Command to perform ECHO KONICHIWA out of COMMANDS.BAT
FINDSTR ::3 COMMANDS.BAT | START /B
```

That way I don't have to output the line to another bat file, it just runs the command instantly.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [Mechaflash's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432751/batch-script-call-another-batch-script-to-call-line-to-perform-certain-command/7435189#7435189) answer but makes use of `findstr` instead of `find`.

**master.bat**

```
echo abcd &rem line1
echo hello &rem line2
echo notepad &rem line3
echo public &rem line4
echo wind &rem line5
echo balance &rem line5
```

**command.bat**

```
@echo off

findstr line%1 master.bat > temp.bat & temp.bat
```