# Alarm clock service in Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'm trying to create an alarm clock service via CMD Prompt. The service can be programmed to a certain time, and will play a song and ask a question before terminating. I'm running into two difficulties:

1) The command prompt window opens and then closes when it reaches the `if/else` statement (doesn't even pause after the `if/else` as coded below). Is my `if` statement faulty? It was literally working up until the time changed to 11:00 PM, and then the faulty behavior began.

2) Using `more` in the for loop to read the nth line of a file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6410343/3746582) gave an error saying `Cannot access file (filename)` before the if/else statement started to fault. Any thoughts?

```
@ECHO OFF
rem Alarm generated that won't turn off until interacted by user.

rem Get time
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

if %mytime% == 2328 (
    start wmplayer "C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3"
    pause

    rem Stop music with user input
    taskkill /im "wmplayer.exe"

    rem Pick random question
    SET /a _rand=%RANDOM%*216929/32768+1 
    SET /a _rand-=1
    For /f "tokens=6-7 delims=," %%a in (more +%_rand% 'JEOPARDY_CSV.txt') do (set /a myquestion = %%a && set /a myanswer = %%b)
    set /p userinp=Answer the question of the day! %myquestion%:%=%     
    pause
    ) else (
    pause
    )
pause
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to both of your problems:

### Problem 1:

The most likely problem is the variable `mytime` does not have a value set (Which suggests the for loop before it doesn't work). As a general precaution you should always use `"`'s when in if statements.

```
if "%mytime%" EQU "2328" (
```

As for your for-loop I would recommend instead using variable syntax instead (`set /? | more +78`). Replace your for-loop with:

```
set mytime=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
```

And that should fix problem 1 (as in your if statement should not crash).

### Problem 2:

In batch, referring to a variable within `(`...brackets...`)` you will refer to the value of the variable **BEFORE** the start of the brackets. Hence your variables don't exist!

To fix this we use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (`Setlocal /?`) and inside the brackets we replace `%` with `!`.

One Last thing which might explain why your code is not working is there is no **Loop**! You could use a simple goto loop. I have added the goto statement to your code.

I also added `"usebackq"` to the for statement so the `more` command works.

So your finished code should look like:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Alarm Clock

:loop
set mytime=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%

if "%mytime%" EQU "2328" (
    start wmplayer "C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3"
    pause

    rem Stop music with user input
    taskkill /im "wmplayer.exe"

    rem Pick random question
    SET /a _rand=!RANDOM!*216929/32768+1 
    SET /a _rand-=1
    For /f "usebackq tokens=6-7 delims=," %%a in ('more +!_rand! JEOPARDY_CSV.txt') do (set /a myquestion = %%a && set /a myanswer = %%b)
    set /p userinp=Answer the question of the day !myquestion!:%=%     
    pause
    ) else (
    goto loop
    )
pause
endlocal
```

Which should work for you.

Comment: Thank you @Monacraft - Problem 1 is solved by your solution, but Problem 2 is only partially solved. First- I needed to put quotes (" ") around the `more +!_rand!...` statement to read the text file properly. Unfortunately, in the command window, the text file is not being read properly and the variables `myquestion` and `myanswer` are not being set at all. This is seen when trying to access `!myquestion!` . Any thoughts? Finally, could you explain how there was no loop in my code? Or why a loop is needed? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try my edited code solution. Also if my solution is helpful don't forget to mark it right

Comment: Unfortunately the script is not letting me access the file with the `Cannot access file (file directory)` error. This error only arises when using the `more` command- do you have any suggestions as to why that is? Thanks again for the help so far!