# Rename Window File using CMD

Tags: cmd, rename

how to remove hyphen "-" in a batch of document that does not have a consistence structure.

```
eg
1XXXXXX RevX - XXX
1XXXXXX RevX (this file dont have -)
1XXXXXX RevX - XXXXX
1XXXXXX RevXX - XXXXX
```

```
intended output
1XXXXXX RevX XXX
1XXXXXX RevX 
1XXXXXX RevX XXXXX
1XXXXXX RevXX XXXXX
```

I have tried `ren "*-*" "*/*"` but it is not working. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Well, `"*/*` is not part of a legal filename in Windows, because you can't have a forward slash in a filename. Try something else instead, like renaming to a valid filename.

Comment: I read else where that the / is to replace `-` with `space`. I don;t need the `/`, i just want `-` to be removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429604/62576 shows a way to do it in VBScript. You can't do that with a simple `ren` command.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, you can't simply use `ren` with wildcards here.
Therefore you have to process each file on its own. `cmd` provides the `for` loop to do so:

```
for %%a in (*-*) do call :removedash "%%a"
goto :eof

:removedash
set "name=%~n1"          &REM take name only            
set "name=%name:-=%"     &REM remove dashes
set "name=%name:  = %"   &REM replace double-spaces with single-space
ECHO ren "%~1" "%name%%~x1"
```

Note: if you have a space both before and after the dash, removing the dash results in two consecutive spaces, which you probably don't want, so we replace them with a single space. We could just replace `<space><dash><space>` with `<space>`, but I'm not sure if we can trust there *are* spaces around the dash.

NOTE: I "disarmed" the `ren` command for security reasons. Remove the `ECHO` when you are sure it does what you want.